# FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized error while starting hybris server in debug mode

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

While trying to start my `hybrisserver` in debug mode I got the following error messages and `hybrisserver` stopped. I tried but not able to solve. Any help please.

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)<br/>
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Permission denied<br/>
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)<br/>
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]<br/>
JVM exited while loading the application.<br/>
Reloading Wrapper configuration...<br/>
Launching a JVM...<br/>
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)<br/>
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Permission denied<br/>
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)<br/>
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]<br/>
JVM exited while loading the application.<br/>
```

There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds. 
 Giving up.
  There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.

```
<-- Wrapper Stopped<br/>
```

An error occurred in the process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@thijsraets is correct. Either you have to check where is the port (8000) has been occupied or you can override the default value to something else in local.properties file.

```
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8001,suspend=n
```

Run "ant all". This will configure debug for port 8001.

OR

You can change the JVM parameters in wrapper-debug.conf file...

```
wrapper.java.additional.23=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8001,suspend=n
```

Answer (score 3):

People who encounter this problem seem to already have something else bound to the debug port, try changing the port in: `tomcat.debugjavaoptions`

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me and tried to kill the server and restarted it safely. I followed these steps:

> > 1. ps aux | grep java  . this will help me to find the PID , Process ID
> > 2. kill -9 PID

If you want to kill all the tomcat processes you can do

> > pkill -9 -f tomcat

this will restart the server safely.

Comment: A process kill -9 doesn't restart the server safely